# Unity3d Select child object by touch

Tags: unity-game-engine, scripting, monodevelop

My problem occurs when I touch the child object (it's a pillow on a sofa).

`collider.transform.name` always returns the parent's name. I'm trying to change the selected object color. The color change script works well except that it always returns the parent.

An example: I want to change only the pillow color on the sofa but it changes the sofa color and not the pillows. I'm new to Unity.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class objectSelect : MonoBehaviour {
    public Text tex;
    public Text tex2;
    public Transform obj1;
    public string rr;

    void Start () {
    }

    void Update () {
        Touch touch = Input.touches [0];
        Vector3 pos = touch.position;
        if (Input.touchCount > 0 && touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began) {
            RaycastHit hit;
            Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay (pos); 
            Vector3 planePoint = ray.GetPoint(0.0f);
            if (Physics.Raycast(ray,out hit))
            {
                obj1 = hit.transform;
                tex.text = obj1.transform.gameObject.GetInstanceID().ToString();
                tex2.text = hit.collider.transform.name;
                RR=obj1.transform.gameObject.GetInstanceID().ToString();
            }
        }
    }

    public string getselectedObj() {
        return obj1.transform.gameObject.GetInstanceID().ToString();
    }
    public string r() {
        return "rrrrrR";
    }
    public string RR { 
        get {
            return rr;
        }
        set {
            rr = value;
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: You must have a separate collider on the pillow to do that.

Comment: i have got box colliders on sofa and on pillows

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of your sofa's hierarchy and highlight which object you expect the ray to hit?

Comment: Added screen shot. If user touch sofa i want to hit sofa, if user touch the pillow i want to select pillow

Comment: And I'll say this, Unity Answers is a much better suited site for Unity related questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Box Collider of the sofa contains both the pillow colliders. As a result, no ray or in fact no object can touch the pillow collider, because it is inside the sofa collider, which is why the sofa collider will always be touched first. The solution to this can be to make a compound collider for the sofa, that is make one collider for the base of the sofa, add it to the "sofa" game object, make two-three more colliders for the sofa's armrests and backrests and add them as children of the collider.

Answer (score 0):

Your pillow colliders are inside the Sofa colliders. That is why on touch, your game is finding sofa prior to pillows. Try to customize the sofa colliders. By adding more than one BoxColliders in a way so that pillows will come forward.

Comment: Beat me to the chase!

Comment: @EvilTak 3 answers. :P :D

Answer (score 0):

expected Solution!

use **Mess collider** rather than **box collider** for sofa and pillow this will solve pillow unreachable issue.

I use same solution for one of client having same scenario!

```
    objectSelect theScript = touchObj.GetComponent<objectSelect>();
    Renderer x = theScript.obj1.GetComponent<Renderer>();
    x.material.color = <Color you want to apply>;
```

**touchObj**  object that return reference to the object you touch ex. sofa or pillow